# Invert a function via a lookup

Tags: r

The goal of this function is to an invert an income tax function. That is, given the tax paid and the financial year, the function should return the taxable income for that year. I would prefer to invert the income tax function rather than create a new function (so that changes to the income tax function will not require changes to the inverse function).

Taxable income (i.e. the function's output) may be assumed to be nonnegative integer.

The function requires the use of the grattan package (as well as `data.table`)

```
require(grattan) || devtools::install_github("HughParsonage/grattan")
require(data.table)
```

My initial attempt was a basic while loop:

```
inverse_income_while <- function(tax, fy.year = "2012-13"){
  income <- 0L
  while(grattan::income_tax(income, fy.year = fy.year) <= tax){
    income <- income + 1000L
  }

  income <- income - 999L

  while(grattan::income_tax(income, fy.year = fy.year) <= tax){
    income <- income + 1L
  }

  return(income)
}
```

This function only works on a length-one input. To extend this to a vector, I used a lookup table and a rolling join. I also account for the one-to-many property of the `income_tax` function below the tax-free threshold (e.g. for 2012-13, $18,200 although technically above due to offsets) through an option `zero.tax.income`.

My concerns are

1. speed
2. the use of the 3.79 magic number
3. the use of the `ifelse` function (which `lineprof` suggests is a bottleneck) in order to ensure temporary invertibility.

---

```
inverse_income_lookup3 <- function(tax, fy.year = "2012-13", zero.tax.income = "maximum"){
  # This function creates a lookup table of incomes taxes 
  zeroes <- tax == 0
  # We now designate the range of incomes to search over. 
  # Always check up to $100,000. There, the ratio of income to 
  # tax is at most 3.79 and decreases thereafter (2012-13).
  income.range <- seq(0L, max(ceiling(max(tax) * 3.79), 100000L), by = 1L)  
  input <- data.table::data.table(taxes = ifelse(zeroes, 1, tax))  # ensure a one-to-one relationship
  temp <- data.table::data.table(incomes = income.range)
  temp$taxes <- grattan::income_tax(temp$incomes, fy.year = fy.year)
  data.table::setkey(temp, taxes)
  # tbl <- temp[input, roll=-Inf]  # LOOCF, all taxes are invertible
  tbl <- data.table:::`[.data.table`(temp, input, roll=-Inf)

  out <- tbl$incomes
  # Take care of zeroes
  if(any(zeroes)){
    if (zero.tax.income == "zero"){
      out[zeroes] <- 0L
    } else {
      if(is.numeric(zero.tax.income)){
        out[zeroes] <- zero.tax.income
      } else {
        max.zero.tax.income <- inverse_income_while(0, fy.year = fy.year) - 1
        if (zero.tax.income == "maximum"){
          out[zeroes] <- max.zero.tax.income
        } else {
          if(zero.tax.income == "uniform")
            out[zeroes] <- sample(0:max.zero.tax.income, size = sum(zeroes))
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return(out)
}
```

Comment: How long will the `tax` vector be in the application you have in mind and what would be an acceptable computation time? Are you open to alternatives to a lookup? I'd like to suggest you use a root solver, which is incredibly easy to setup.

Comment: Size: For the most part, less than a million elements, but occasionally in the order of a billion.

Comment: Definitely open to alternatives than a lookup. It seemed an improvement from a basic while loop, but nothing more.